# How to store, find , then import a text file on iPad air 2 using Pythonista?

Tags: python, ios, ipad, pythonista

Using an iPad, I'm attempting to import a text file from the Internet in order to utilize in Python MOOC exercise "hangman" from edx:

> For this problem, you will need the code files ps3_hangman.py and words.txt. Right-click on each and hit "Save Link As". Be sure to save them in same directory. Open and run the file ps3_hangman.py without making any modifications to it, in order to ensure that everything is set up correctly.

Thing is, these seem not easy options on an iPad.  I managed to copy and paste the **hangman.py** file into a new Pythonista file, but....

- how to handle the large text file?
- Where do I store it as a text file, find it, then import it into this iPad program?

No problem on Windows.  Apple does not allow a `file.open()` type operation.

Comment: I apologize for the improper format.  Love the site, but don't ever post.

Comment: I neglected to thank you @Sathya for editing my original post.  Comparing your edited version to my original is embarrassing.  Yours is cleaner, more to the point.  Will do better next time.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

One way you could do this if you don't have access to a Mac/PC, i.e. entirely on your iPad in Pythonista:

- Copy the URL of the text file in Safari (tap and hold the link)
- In Pythonista, switch to the interactive prompt (swipe from right to left)
- Enter the following two lines:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve('<paste copied url here>', 'words.txt')
```

You could also write these two lines in a regular script instead of using the interactive prompt. But you'll probably just need this once.